# Comparison of sub- and parent classes

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, mypy

### Issue

When implementing a comparison method between two classes the result is not as expected.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, A):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.name == other.name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, B):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.name == other.name and self.value == other.value

a = A("a")
b = B("a", 1)

print(a == b)  # True
print(b == a)  # True
```

What I want is that different instances of these classes with different properties are not equal, so I'd expect `False` in both cases.

The reason that we get `True` instead is because we return `NotImplemented` in the `__eq__` method of `B` if the other object is not an instance of B. This causes the `__eq__` method of `A` to be called. As `B` is a subclass of `A`, `isinstance(b, A)` returns True.

### Solution (Try 1)

Instead of checking using `isinstance(other, A)` we can use `type(other) is A`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not type(other) is A:
            return NotImplemented
        return self.name == other.name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not type(other) is B:
            return NotImplemented
        return self.name == other.name and self.value == other.value

a = A("a")
b = B("a", 1)

print(a == b)  # False
print(b == a)  # False
```

This works as expected, however mypy does not like it:

```
error: Returning Any from function declared to return "bool"  [no-any-return]
error: "object" has no attribute "name"  [attr-defined]
error: Returning Any from function declared to return "bool"  [no-any-return]
error: "object" has no attribute "name"  [attr-defined]
error: "object" has no attribute "value"  [attr-defined]
```

### Solution (Try 2)

As far as I could figure out, in order for mypy to like the solution, the `isinstance` checks have to stay. So I added the type check to the value comparison.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, A):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.name == other.name and type(other) is A

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(name)
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, B):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.name == other.name and self.value == other.value and type(other) is B

a = A("a")
b = B("a", 1)

print(a == b)  # False
print(b == a)  # False
```

Now mypy is fine with the code, but pylint still doesn't like the solution:

```
C0123: Using type() instead of isinstance() for a typecheck. (unidiomatic-typecheck)
```

How can I resolve this issue correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You're very close!

The standard process for checking if two objects use the same class is this:

```py
if type(x) == type(y):
```

However, a lot of linters will complain and ask you to use `isinstance` as they think that you want it to evaluate to true for subclasses too. Best you can do is ignore them.

Hope this solves your issue!

Edit:
You should be able to use `is` instead of `==`.

Comment: Apologies if this doesn't answer your question. My brain is in shutdown mode and I may have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Type checking as you suggest will work, but neither mypy nor pylint will accept this solution. I'd have to add three comments to get rid of the messages. This raises the question if this is actually the way to go.

Comment: You could try equating the `__class__` attribute of the objects instead. That might shut the linters up.

Comment: That does work, if I also keep `isinstance()`: `if not isinstance(other, B) or not self.__class__ == other.__class__: return NotImplemented`. Doesn't look great though, does it?

Comment: Its not perfect, no. But if you are dead set on appeasing the linters, it may be your only option.

Comment: And `type(other) is type(self)`?